# Why am i getting a NullReferenceException when i switch platform to Android in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, virtual-reality, build-settings

The steps i did:

```
Assets>Import package>Environment

Assets>Import package>custom package>GoogleVRForUnity_1.120.0.unitypackage

GameObject> 3D object> Terrain

Save Scene

Build Settings> add open scene

Build Settings> Switch platform - Android
```

Error details:

```
 NullReferenceException
 UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.MobileControlRig.EnableControlRig
 (Boolean enabled) (at Assets/Standard
 Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/MobileControlRig.cs:89)
 UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.MobileControlRig.CheckEnableControlRig
 () (at Assets/Standard
 Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/MobileControlRig.cs:80)
 UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.MobileControlRig.OnActiveBuildTargetChanged
 (BuildTarget previousTarget, BuildTarget newTarget) (at
 Assets/Standard
 Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/MobileControlRig.cs:98)
 UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnActiveBuildTargetChanged
 (BuildTarget previousPlatform, BuildTarget newPlatform) (at
 C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:345)
 UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces:OnActiveBuildTargetChanged(BuildTarget,
 BuildTarget)
```

Please do help. I've been stuck on it.

**Unity 2017.3.0f3**

Comment: Any idea? I'm dealing with a similar issue.

Comment: That's probably a Unity bug, you don't have to worry about it.  
After you switch platforms to Android, make sure that you go to the player settings and set your package name and key.

Comment: Good point, I totally overlooked player settings by trying to export the project. I'm going to take a look at it next. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for those who are using UnityStandardAssets, are building for Android and are making a 2D application/game:
Go to build settings and click on player settings. Then expand "Other Settings". After you scroll down you'll find a textbox with the name "Script Define Symbols". Enter this without the "" symbols: "CROSS_PLATFORM_INPUT;MOBILE_INPUT". I'm using Unity 2020.3.1f1 Personal.